# How to make ReactJs and AngularJs co-existing in a ASP.Net Core web application?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, asp.net-core

We have build a website based on ASP.net core serving razor cshtml pages. Each page is like its own independent spa with its own Angular.Module. Each part of the application is quite independent with only a few things shared between them like login etc.

It has worked fine, but now new developers have joined the team and want to work on new modules using React. My question is from development point of view:

- Can AngularJs (version 1.7 i.e. less than 2) and React co-exists?
- How to include ReactJs to an existing asp.net application without using Node or Webpack

Comment: I found https://jonhilton.net/use-react-in-your-existing-asp-net-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible for them to coexist, look at this link
[ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact)

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes, I looked at the site but I dont want to inject or interaction between them, just existing independently within same asp.net core application.